# Set a variable to true if all the props are defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

What is the simplest way to set a variable to true if all the required props for the rendered component are defined?

E.g:

```
  renderThing() {
    const {
      bookState,
      totalPrice,
      agentWebPriceDelta,
      numberOfChargeablePassengers,
    } = this.props;

      const requiredProps = bookState !== 'undefined' && totalPrice !== 'undefined' && agentWebPriceDelta !== 'undefined' && numberOfChargeablePassengers !== 'undefined';

      return requiredProps && (
          <ComponentToBeRendered
            ...
          />
        );
    }
  }
```

This is to stop getting errors like:

> Required prop `totalPrice` was not specified in `ComponentToBeRendered`.'

Comment: `if (bookState !== undefined && totalPrice !== undefined &&... )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: remove the quotes around `undefined`:

```js
const requiredProps = bookState !== undefined && totalPrice !== undefined && agentWebPriceDelta !== undefined && numberOfChargeablePassengers !== undefined;
```

You can also use **[Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)** like this (not sure if it's more readable):

```js
const requiredProps = [
  bookState,
  totalPrice,
  agentWebPriceDelta,
  numberOfChargeablePassengers
].reduce((prev, value) => prev && value !== undefined, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

As you just want to get rid of the warning I recommend to remove the "isRequired" from your properties. e.g:

**ES6**

```
YourComponent.propTypes = {
  //instead of this
  bookState: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  //try this
  bookState: React.PropTypes.string,
};
```

**< ES6**

```
propTypes: {
  //instead of this
  bookState: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  //try this
  bookState: React.PropTypes.string,
},
```

If you specify a property as required in react you will always receive this error when a required property is missing. If you also want to render a Component without all properties, you should set defaultProps for the ones that could be missing (and are not required). So always think about when it is useful to set a property required and when not.

PS.: I think those errors/warnings only show in development mode, but I'm not 100% sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

Undefined is a primitive in javascript.In your code you compare the values with the string 'undefined'

`typeof  bookState !== 'undefined'` or `bookState !== undefined`

```
  const requiredProps = bookState !== undefined && totalPrice !== undefined && agentWebPriceDelta !== undefined && numberOfChargeablePassengers !== undefined;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using React's [propTypes](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) to enforce the required fields. For your example, after the ComponentToBeRendered class definition, you would include:

```
ComponentToBeRendered.propTypes = {
  bookState: React.PropTypes.isRequired,
  totalPrice: React.PropTypes.isRequired,
  agentWebPriceDelta: React.PropTypes.isRequired,
  numberofChargeablePassengers: React.PropTypes.isRequired
};
```

Using propTypes on your component will enforce the field requirement. You can also use propTypes to ensure the property type is correct.

Comment: Yes, this is what I already have. But in order to render that component with those required props I need to check that all those exist before rendering the component. Hence my code above.